# Getting a file from an incoming POST HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, file, post, httpwebrequest

I am being sent a Http POST request that includes a file. How can I get the file out of the HTTPWebRequest?

Comment: Are you embedding the file contents inside the XML?

Answer (score 0):

Request.Files

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/web/httprequestclassfiles.aspx